# How the derivative might fail to exist

Tags: derivatives

Can a function have both a vertical tangent and cusp? Does The function $3x^{1/3}(x+2)$ have a vertical tangent and if so why? I believe that it has a cusp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y'(x) = \dfrac{x+2}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} + 3\sqrt[3]x$, and $y'(0) = \text{undefined}$ .Thus there is a vertical tangent at $(0,0)$.

Comment: So a vertical tangent is when y' is undefined?

Comment: according to my book the vertical tangent occurs when "slopes of secant lines approach positive/negative infinity from both sides"  (Finney Demana Waits Kennedy). The function $3x^{1/3}(x+2)$ doesn't satisfy said condition.

Comment: @AmandaKelius, I agree with that book's definition. As the function is defined at zero it can't have a vertical tangent (which I'd rather call asympote as Mahidevran does, though perhaps these two are different).

Comment: @Timbuc: That is incorrect.  $\sqrt[3]{x}$, if defined on $\mathbb R$ to be the inverse of $x^3$, does have a vertical tangent at $(0,0)$.  Same is true if you multiply it by $3(x+2)$.

Comment: @Amanda: Why are you claiming it doesn't satisfy the condition?

Comment: @JonasMeyer, I can't really say. First, that "vertical tangent" thing sounds a little weird to me. I'd go for asymptote but I realize these may be two different things, though I can't really think ofanything really important or interesting about "verticl tangents". Perhaps they have some use similar to asymptotes, but I don't know it.

Comment: @Timbuc: Tangent lines to a curve and asymptotes are very different.

Comment: Oh, I know that now, @JonasMeyer...yet I can't see how tangent lines can help for something, either invertigating the function, to draw it or whatever.

Comment: OK.  I suppose this isn't the place to convince you that tangents are helpful, so I'll stop.

Answer (score 2):

Typically terminology distinguishes between cusps and vertical tangents.   A cusp is where slopes approach $+\infty$ on one side, and $-\infty$ on the other.  For vertical tangents, slopes approach $+\infty$ on both sides, or $-\infty$ on both sides.

For example, the real cube root function has a vertical tangent (with slopes approaching $+\infty$) at $(0,0)$, whereas $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x^2}$ has a cusp (slopes on the left approaching $-\infty$, slopes on the right approaching $+\infty$) at $(0,0)$.

Your function behaves like the real cube root function at $(0,0)$, and has a vertical tangent there, not a cusp.  That is, unless by $x^{1/3}$ you meant something other than the real cube root function.